# Anime with house with girls with different hobbies?

Tags: sister-princess

A few year ago, I saw an episode of an old anime. This anime was probably from the late 90s or early 2000s. It starts with a teenager on a boat that was talking to the boat driver and thought he was going to an acadamy on an island. But actually it's just some house or castle. (I don't remember which.)

In this house were a lot of girls of different ages, younger and older then the boy. Each girl has a different kind of hobby (I would say) like magic (with cards and a broom) or sports.

That's everything I know.

Comment: My english isnt very good since its my second languge and im self-taught,sorry for my mistakes

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like [Sister Princess](http://myanimelist.net/anime/836/Sister_Princess). It came out in the early 2000s and started with the main character, Wataru, on a boat going to an island with a big mansion. The mansion had Wataru's twelve younger sisters. One sister, Chikage, was a magician who had tarot cards and a crystal ball, and I believe also a broom, as you describe in the question. Another girl, I believe named RinRin, was a sports nut. There was also a girl who was a detective (Yotsuba), a girl who was a French noblewoman (Aria), a girl who was trendy (Sakuya), and several others.

[image: Sister Princess cast]

Comment: @Niko144 If this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark underneath the voting buttons. You and I will both get some reputation for that, and it tells other users that the question is answered.